# Owl Carousel not working in any version of IE

Tags: owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel in my website, it works fine in all browsers except IE(any version), Any help on how could i solve it? The carousel does not slide when in IE.

Owl Version : OwlCarousel v1.3.3
My jQuery version : 1.12.4

Comment: have you add `shiv, shim` or `mordernizer`

Comment: Yes i have added shiv but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hi,

I updated the both the owl css and js to owl.carousel1.3.3.css and owl.carousel1.3.3.js resp. and it started working in IE.

I had missed upgrading the css file to owl.carousel1.3.3.css

Thanks,
Yaman Agrawal